# Couldn't find ID from document in MongoDB collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I'm trying to get single ID of a document, I tried something like this, before it worked, but since new version update it says that imported `mongo` from `mongodb` does not exist. This means that `mongo` library doesn't longer exist, is there any other way of doing this?

So here is my following response which I want to send:

```
    app.get ('/products/:id', async (req , res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    let db = await connect();
    console.log("params: ",id);
    let doc = await db.collection("posts").findOne({_id: mongo.ObjectId(id)});
    console.log(doc)
    res.json(doc)
});
```

I used this: `import mongo from 'mongodb';` and when I try to get single ID from a document it says: `Cannot read property 'ObjectId' of undefined`.

Comment: A more minimal example would be `import mongo from 'mongodb'; console.log(mongo);`.  If you don't see output, the import has failed. The question title would then become: "How do I import mongo?".  Getting a value from the database probably works fine once you've got the library

Comment: @danh yeah sorry for the non-specific expression, but the thing is that `import mongo from 'mongodb'` worked before for me and now it doesn't, it says it's undefined when I do `console.log`, so is there any new way of doing this?

Comment: Is it a node project?  If so, does it mention mongo in package.json?  Have you done an npm install?  Also see answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35962879/how-to-import-mongodb-using-es6-style-imports

Comment: @danh yeah it's node project I'm doing this with Vue framework. Yes I've done that, I already have data on mongo database, I used this before too but it seems that something changed.

Comment: I tried with `require` and it still doesn't work.